# Passing arguments to functions in javascript

Tags: javascript

I am trying to change myprop's value with option 3 and 4, but with no success. Why?

```
object1 = {myprop:"value1", ....};  

button1.addEventListener('click',  function(e){
 object1.myMethod("value2"); // 1) working.   myMethod is a method that sets myprop's value  
 object1.myprop="value2";    // 2) working 

 myFunction1(object1.myMethod);   // 3) not working
 myFunction2(object1.myprop);     // 4) not working
});

function myFunction1(src) {
 src("value2");
}
function myFunction2(src) {
 src="value2";
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you define your anonymous function to handle the `click` event (`button1.addEventListener('click',  function(e) {...}`), the value of `object1.myMethod` and `object1.myprop` are captured in the closure.

What it means is: you are defining a function, and this function, when executed, will need some values that are in scope when it was defined, but not when it will be executed (both `object1.myMethod` and `object1.myprop`). The function is being defined right there in your code, but is being passed around as a parameter and will be called far away from there, whenever the `click` event happen on the button.

What happens is that that `object1.myMethod` and `object1.myprop` are evaluated to its values and captured in the function's closure, to be available later when the function will be executed (you don't see any of this happening, it just happens).

So, your approach won't work here. I see one alternative for setting the property, that is pass the object in which you want to change the value, and pass the name of the property that you want to change.

```
// 1 way to make the property call work
object1 = {myProp:"value1"};

button1.addEventListener('click',  function(e){
  myFunction2(object1, 'myProp');
});

function myFunction2(src, prop) {
  src[prop]="value3";
};
```

For the methods parts, I can see 3 ways to make it work (actually 4, if I've used `apply` instead of `call`).

1. First is the same as in the case of the property: you pass the `object1` and the name of the slot where is the function.
2. Second, you can pass the `object1` and the function, and later `call` your function in the context of `object1`.
3. Third, you can create, from your `object1.myMethod`, a new function that will be bound to `object1` (that is, `object1` will be its context), no matter where you will call it later. That is done with `bind`.

Examples:

```
// 3 ways to make the method call work
object1 = {myMethod:function(someParam){console.log(someParam)}};

button1.addEventListener('click',  function(e){
  myFunction1(object1, 'myMethod');
  myFunction3(object1, object1.myMethod);
  myFunction4(object1.myMethod.bind(object1, 'value3'));
});

function myFunction1(src, prop) {
  src[prop]("value3");
};

function myFunction3(src, method) {
  method.call(src, 'value3');
};

function myFunction4(func) {
  func();
};
```

Answer (score 2):

You are passing the *value* of `object1.myMethod`/`object.myprop` which gets *copied* to the `src` variable.

You then either call the function (but in a different context so the value of `this` inside it is different) or overwrite the value of `src` while leaving the original property alone.

If you want the function to be called in the right context, you need to pass that context in with `call()` or `apply()`.

If you want to overwrite the `myprop` property of the object stored in `object1` then you have to have a reference to the value of `object1` and set the property on that.